# Does Azure support hashbang urls for Path Based Routing in Application Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I have a couple of webapps behind an application gateway.  I am using Path Based Routing to send traffic between the two.  Does the application gateway support rules that include #!s?  For Example:

Rule 1: App/Index/10#!
Rule 2: App/Index/100

Answer (score 0):

'#' as regular expression character is not supported. Only terminal * is supported currently.